# Circular permutations

Tags: julia, permutation

Given a vector `z = [1, 2, 3]`, I want to create a vector of vectors with all circular permutations of `z` (i.e. `zp = [[1,2,3], [3,1,2], [2,3,1]]`).

I can print all elements of `zp` with

```
for i in 1:length(z)
    push!(z, shift!(z)) |> println
end
```

How can I store the resulting permutations? Note that

```
zp = Vector(length(z))
for i in 1:length(z)
    push!(z, shift!(z))
    push!(zp, z)
end
```

doesn't work as it stores the same vector `z` 3 times in `zp`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

One way would just be to copy the vector before pushing it:

```
z = [1, 2, 3];

zp = Vector();
for i in 1:length(z)
    push!(z, shift!(z))
    push!(zp, copy(z))
end
```

gives me

```
julia> zp
3-element Array{Any,1}:
 [2,3,1]
 [3,1,2]
 [1,2,3]
```

But I tend to prefer avoiding mutating operations when I can.  So I'd instead write this as

```
julia> zp = [circshift(z, i) for i=1:length(z)]
3-element Array{Array{Int64,1},1}:
 [3,1,2]
 [2,3,1]
 [1,2,3]
```

Comment: I didn't know about `circshift`, I will use that instead.

Comment: If the application allows the use of overlapping arrays for circular shifts: `allcircular(v) = begin v2=repmat(v,2); L=length(v); [view(v2,i:i+L-1) for i=1:L] ; end` does the trick. It runs 2x faster than solution in the answer, and can take way less memory on long arrays. But overlapping condition is very error-prone if data not used read-only.

Comment: @DanGetz: nice!  I've gotten myself into trouble using stride tricks in the past, and this kind of access is almost never a bottleneck in critical paths in my code, so I tend to avoid clever views.  But it's still pretty slick. :-)

Answer (score 4):

This seems to execute pretty quick on my machine (faster than a comprehension):

```
julia> z=[1,2,3]
3-element Array{Int64,1}:
 1
 2
 3

julia> zp=Vector{typeof(z)}(length(z))
3-element Array{Array{Int64,1},1}:
 #undef
 #undef
 #undef

julia> for i=1:length(z)
         zp[i]=circshift(z,i-1)
       end

julia> zp
3-element Array{Array{Int64,1},1}:
 [1,2,3]
 [3,1,2]
 [2,3,1]

julia>
```